# limit flextable.sethtml to same line

Tags: java, gwt

I have FlexTable layout = new FlexTable();
But When I write a text as 
layout.setHTML(1, 0, "Thehe  Color is :");
The colon appears in the next line. How to limit the whole text to a single line.
Can some one help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to replace your spaces with `&nbsp;`

```
layout.setHTML(1, 0, "The&nbsp;Color&nbsp;is&nbsp;:");
```